# Display the HTML page on webview to fit the content

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiwebview

I am doing an application for both iPhone and iPad. I have taken a `UIViewController` and added a subview `UIWebView` where I need to dipslay html pages.

I am able to display the html page on the webview, but the problem is the html page doesn't get fit into the webview. I tried with :

```
webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

When I have done this, the data is appearing in veryshort.

Can anyone Kindly help me to sort out this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your HTML page,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Comment: i have saved my html pages in a folder i am accessing those from the folder when i display i on the webview the some page content cannot be seen

Comment: @IphoneDevloper: Okay Deifnately